# How to do predictions with tf.dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have an issue with tf.datasets and tf.keras.predict(). I don't know why the length of the output array of predict() is larger than the original lenght of data used. Here is a sketch:
Before I used arrays. And if I applied predict() on a array of lenght x I get an output of lenght x... This is my expected behaviour.

I have a csv of test data with some lenght (10000). Now  I use

```
LABEL_COLUMN = 'label'
LABELS = [0, 1]

def get_dataset(file_path, **kwargs):
  dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
      file_path,
      batch_size=1, # Artificially small to make examples easier to show.
      label_name=LABEL_COLUMN,
      na_value="?",
      num_epochs=1,
      ignore_errors=True,
      **kwargs)
  return dataset
```

to convert this to a tf.dataset.

```
val='data/test.csv'
val_data= get_dataset(val)
```

Now using

```
scores=bert_model.predict(val_data)
```

gives an array ouput which is very much larger than of the original csv file (10000)...

I am really off. Also I ask myself how does keras know what "keys" of the tf.dataset to use for predictrions.

The structure of the 1. elemnt of the dataset looks like "val[0]":

```
({'input_ids': <tf.Tensor: shape=(15,), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([    3,  2019,   479,  1169,  4013, 26918,   259,     4, 14576,
        3984,   889,   648,  1610, 26918,     4])>, 'token_type_ids': <tf.Tensor: shape=(15,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])>, 'attention_mask': <tf.Tensor: shape=(15,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])>}, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=0>)
```

1. why does my label column has no key with name "label"? The first 3 keys all have their names and the model is trained with these 3 columns.

I use above structure with label column as input for predict...

Any idea? Is it due to the function of making a dataset from a csv?

Comment: Have you checked the size of dataset, not the CSV file, to see if it really contains 10,000 samples?

Comment: How woould I do that? SInce I use to make it from a csv file, it returns a flat dataset where cardinality gives -2

Comment: If eager mode is enabled, what is the result of `len(dataset)`?

Comment: I use tf2. Do I need to enable eager mode extra?

Comment: No, if you have not disabled it. It would be enabled by default.

Comment: It says that dataset length is unknown. I have a flatmapdatset.

Comment: <FlatMapDataset shapes: ({input_ids: (None,), token_type_ids: (None,), attention_mask: (None,)}, ()), types: ({input_ids: tf.int32, token_type_ids: tf.int32, attention_mask: tf.int32}, tf.int64)>
({'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), 'token_type_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), 'attention_mask': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)}, TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))

Comment: It is a datset from tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()

Comment: What is the shape of `scores` then?